# QT InApp Purchasing Non-renewing subscriptions

Tags: c++, qt, in-app-purchase

I read about [QT Purchasing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtpurchasing-gettingstarted-cpp.html) and checked the [purchasable content types](https://support.apple.com/en-me/HT202023) in apple. However, i offer training materials and i wonder if it is possible to offer non-renuable subscriptions with Qt. Any experience is appreciated.